# creating json structure from dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe which is product of left join. Now I want to create json structure.

I tried using different option but I was not able create it. Here is my dataframe :

```
Col1    col2    col3    col4
1111    name    null    null
1112    name1   abcd    def
1112    name1   DEFG    ABXC
```

The desired json structure is :

```
{col1 : 1111, col2 : name , detial: {col3:,col4:}}
{col1 : 1112, col2 : name1 , detial: {{col3:abcd,col4:def},{col3:DEFG,col4:ABXC}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created the data from your sample dataset and created a dataframe out of it.You can use the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, DataFrame,SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import json
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col1=1111,col2="name",col3=None,col4=None),Row(col1=1112,col2="name1",col3="abcd",col4="def"),Row(col1=1112,col2="name1",col3="DEFG",col4="ABXC")])

ndata = data.select(struct("col1","col2",struct("col3","col4").alias("details")).alias("data"))

dataList = list(map(json.loads,ndata.toJSON().collect()))
```

The above code returns the result as a list of dictionaries in python.

Comment: You need to import `struct()` from **pyspark.sql** package. `from pyspark.sql import struct`

Comment: @Shane If your query was answered can you accept my answer and close this thread

Comment: I tried your solution but I didnot  got the desired out put which was 

{col1 : 1111, col2 : name , detial: {col3:,col4:}}
{col1 : 1112, col2 : name1 , detial: {{col3:abcd,col4:def},{col3:DEFG,col4:ABXC}}}`  

and your code gives me   

`[u'{"data":{"col1":1111,"col2":"name","details":{}}}', 
u'{"data":{"col1":1112,"col2":"name1","details":{"col3":"abcd","col4":"def"}}}', u'{"data":{"col1":1112,"col2":"name1","details":{"col3":"DEFG","col4":"ABXC"}}}'] `

Comment: I updated my code. You will now get a list of dictionaries where every dictionary is of the structure you desire.

Comment: Now I dont get any output at all... I guess i need to group by the col1 and col2  and values of the details i need to see how to combine.

Comment: can you edit your question and add the code that you are trying? Without that I cannot know what your issue is exactly

Comment: I am using [Code from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299143/how-to-return-an-array-of-struct-or-class-from-udf-into-dataframe-column-value) but now i dont have key value structure... I am only getting values